# How to import an Environment in Matillion

Tags: matillion

I am new to Matilion (Even Matillion is a new tool). I am able to export an existing environment into a JSON file using REST API.

But I observed that there is no REST API endpoint for importing an environment. Rather there is an option for updating an existing environment.

Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Matillion REST API reference link : https://redshift-support.matillion.com/s/article/2920263

Regards,
Neeraj

Comment: Have you tried POST /group/name/<>/project/name/<>/environment/name/<>/update ? Should work as an "insert" as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. No need to specify the environment name in API URL. It will automatically pick the name from JSON file. Below is an example.

```
curl -X POST -u <user_name>:<password> http://<Matillion Instance IP>/rest/v1/group/name/icm/project/name/<>/environment/import -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "<path to exported JSON file>"
```

Comment: You may want to put in fake values for the user value of the curl command.

Comment: Thanks @Nofinator for highlighting. Somehow I missed this.